# Qt Radio button lay text below icon

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to create a QRadioButton such that text shows up below the icon. But QRadioButton does not provide options similar to that of QToolButton, which has options for laying out text and icon. Is there any way to achieve this with QRadioButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just build something yourself. For example put a QLabel below the QRadioButton in a VBoxLayout. You can use a QSpacerItem or two to align everything properly.

[image: Text below QRadioButton]